# "TargetInvocationException" in windows phone 8 sdk

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8

> An exception of type System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.

```
var client = new WebClient(); 
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
           {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
           };
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mylocation.com/myfile.php?userid=xyz"));
```

Comment: This exception means something has crashed when constructing an object.  Add debugging and check what is going on.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, catch the exception, then post the result of `ex.ToString()`. That will display all the inner exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could add a bit of error checking to narrow things down a bit

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
            }
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mylocation.com/myfile.php?userid=xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the data passed between app and Service exceed certain size. For example, when you pass a string larger than 8K chars back to Service, you will get a 404 error. need to change the default configuration to handle large data.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly e.Result or one of its children is null and hence this exception is being thrown.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging and select Enable Just My Code in Visual Studio. That should help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: -1: why would that cause a `TargetInvocationException`?

Comment: I was getting a similar issue in my code when I was trying to query the contacts in my phone via C#. It kept throwing the TargetInvocationException, and this was because one of the children of the objects in e.Result was null.

Comment: The Birthdays field of my Contact object was null. That's what I mean. And why wouldn't you believe me? Why would I make this up in the first place?? This was an issue I faced, so I looked at SO and I managed to solve it late last night, hence the answer, in the hope that someone else can benefit.

Comment: Alright, if you want I'll put in the code. It was a basic Async call to filter my phone contacts that you'll find on dozens of pages (like MSDN). Hence I didn't find the need to actually post it here since it wouldn't be related to the question. My answer, however, is and that's why I provided it. Sorry to say but rather than wisdom of the aged, I am starting to think you are just being a dick!

Comment: No, I could have been a dick a couple of decades ago. It's only in the last 10 years or so that I've learned to find the slack around a loose argument. I suspect that when you try to reproduce the exception, you'll find that TargetInvocationException wasn't caused simply because a data value was `null`. Look at the definition of the exception, "An exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation", and you'll realize that, in general, a `null` is unlikely to cause this exception.

Comment: Possibly, the target if the invocation may have thrown an exception if some value had been null, but the `null` will not have inherently caused the exception.